# module 'networkx' has no attribute 'minimum_cycle_basis'

Tags: python, networkx

> I installed networkx v. 2.1, but when I want to use minimum_cycle_basis, python shows this error
>       module 'networkx' has no attribute 'minimum_cycle_basis'
>   Thanks for helping

Comment: What source code did you type? On my machine, when I `import networkx` and attempt to use `networkx.minimum_cycle_basis`, I cannot replicated your error. Also, which version of python are you using?

Comment: See https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.minimum_cycle_basis.html for example usage

Comment: Please show us a [mcve], with an error traceback and code that reproduces that traceback.

Comment: Meanwhile: two possibilities to look at: (1) Do you have a file named `networkx.py` in your current working directory (or elsewhere on `sys.path`)? If so, `import networkx` is just going to import your script rather than the package you wanted, so you'll get this `AttributeError` for just about everything. (2) Do you have two Python installations, possibly with networkx 2.1 in one of them, but an older version in the other one?